# EJS only showing entire mongo schema, won't display specific data from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to display some data from a mongodb database with EJS and I can only seem to get it to display the entire schema. For example:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
Prices.find({name: "prices"}, function(err, allPrices){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("landing", {prices: allPrices});
    }
});
});
```

When I call that in the landing.ejs as <%= prices %>, it will show the entire schema, which looks like this:

"{ _id: 5a5a475cff999121ec26c1f6, btcPrice: 14237.96986743, ethPrice: 1400.34789518, ltcPrice: 248.07011243, dashPrice: 1094.17162755, name: 'prices', __v: 0 }"

Now when I try to just get a specific part such as <%= prices.btcPrice %>, it doesn't show anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you are returning an array with more than one document , in that case you can loop over your prices object with forEach loop and check price like 
```<% prices.forEach(function(el,index){ %>
<h2> <%= prices.btcPrice %> <h2>
 <% }) %>```

Comment: Try `<%= prices[0].btcPrice %>`

Comment: You're the man, Adam! Thanks a bunch! Although, I wonder why I never have to do that with other cases in the app. Doesn't matter, I guess. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning an array with more than one document , in that case you can loop over your prices object with forEach loop and check price like

```
 <% prices.forEach(function(el,index){ %>
 <h2> <%= prices.btcPrice %> <h2> 
 <% }) %>
```

Comment: Thank you, but Adam Patterson's solution worked perfectly. Not to say this one won't as well, but I'm much too tired to check. God bless